# NameNode: Failed to start namenode in windows 7

Tags: windows, hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I am trying to install Hadoop in windows machine, in middle I got the below error.

**Logs**

```
 17/11/28 16:31:48 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyze 
 Storage(Storage.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1566)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you didn't install [Hadoop winutils](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) or build Hadoop with Native Libraries

> Native IO is mandatory on Windows and without it you will not be able to get your installation working. You must follow all the instructions from BUILDING.txt to ensure that Native IO support is built correctly

[Hadoop2 on Windows](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows)

Answer (score 0):

I also have the similar issue.
I am using Hadoop-2.8.1. These steps solved the error for me.

download the winutils of your version from [GitHub](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)

Copy paste winutils at `<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/`

Also. double check JAVA_HOME environment is correctly set and reference in hadoop-env.cmd file